# How can I sort (order by) in postgres ignoring leading words like "the, a, etc"

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I would like to be able to sort (order by) in postgres ignoring leading words like "the, a, etc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way: script (using your favorite language) the creation of an extra column of the text with noise words removed, and sort on that.

Answer (score 0):

Add a SORT_NAME column that has all that stuff stripped out. For bonus points, use an input trigger to populate it automatically, using your favorite SQL dialect's regex parser or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the column and sorting on the second item in the resulting array:

```
select some_col from some_table order by split_part(some_col, ' ', 2);
```

Comment: This assumes that every value in the column contains a leading word like “the”, which is unlikely except in very specific contexts.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add an extra column. Strip out the leading words in your `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT col FROM table ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(col, 'A ', ''), 'The ', '')
```